# Convert uint32 to int in Go

Tags: go

How do I convert a `uint32` into an `int` in Go?

A little background, I'm reading from a file and this gives me the correct size from a byte array like this:

```
size := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b[4:])
```

However, the `bufio.Discard` func expects an int.  I was able to use fmt to convert size to a string and then use strconv to get it to an int. There has to be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Simple [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), short: `i := int(size)` or  verbose: `var intResult int = int(size)`.

Comment: At first I thought a simple cast would work too.  However, Go does not seem to allow this, the error message is not clear though.

Comment: What error message? Would you care to post it? And simple conversion does work, see this example on the Go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/iPJcmvW4MS

Comment: @icza: That's not a good solution to the question. There's no need for a temporary variable.

Comment: @peterSO Yes, temporary variable is not needed. I didn't mean to imply that, just wanted to show that a simple conversion will do it. It works with or without a temp variable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and
>   `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.

For example,

```
size := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b[4:])
n, err := rdr.Discard(int(size))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I have written too many c-like cast over the years.  Thank you for all the responses!

Answer (score 22):

Simply Use the `int()` cast function